# A rusty place to fly to

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

A red "Indian church-rat" is dreaming of a geometrical shape.

Who has the highest hand?

Hint 1:

> The English "church-rat" and the Japanese "temple-cat" visited their Indian friend, and went to the capital.

Hint 2:

> The "church-rat", the "temple-cat" and the "synagogue-horse" enjoy drinking some milk from their Indian friend.

Hint 3:

> The Indian animal is a holy and submissive bully.

Hint 4:

> The imam is enjoying milk from his animal friend.

Comment: Nice, do I need to know anything about India?

Comment: It is an enigma, more than geographical knowledge

Comment: Is the English church-rat related to Sir Winston Churchill?

Comment: @Gamow No. I just edited in a new tag: Wordplay. The phrase 'church-rat' is indeed a wordplay...:-)

Comment: I don't see how we were supposed to get "cow" from "rat".

Comment: @Deusovi This is were Indian is supposed to give you a hint

Comment: @Enigma: That still doesn't excuse the leap from "rat" to "cow". Where does "rat" fit in? How is a cow an Indian rat?

Comment: @Deusovi Church-rat is a phrase on it own, and the Indian equivalent could be the thing I looked for. But as a single word, I agree that the leap from rat to cow, could be a bit difficult. But again, this is were the hints come in handy...

Comment: @Enigma: Puzzles should be solvable without hints; if hints are an integral part of the puzzle then they should be in the puzzle itself. As it stood originally (and as it currently stands without hints), the puzzle was completely unsolvable. Also, the only source I can find for "church-rat" as an actual phrase is an incredibly racist UrbanDictionary entry.

Comment: I saw that Urban dictionary thing too, but that is not it. "Church-rat" could be used on people, but the prime meaning is perhaps better on a rat (or mouse) living in a church, or more popular in the church organ.

Comment: I am not 100%  sure about the definition of church-rat but if it is same as or near to the definition in UrbanDictionary then I must say, that's **not** how Indian people take cows. There are many festivals celebrated on cows like Pongal, Gowardhar Pooja etc. Eating beef in the state of Maharashtra is against the law. But if UrbanDictionary's definition is wrong, you can just neglect this comment.

Comment: @manshu I was clearly thinking of church-rat as an animal living in a place of worship. But there is really no such thing, therefore the debate here... So another animal living in another place of worship, is nothing different. That is why I eventually found it appropriate to use quotation mark. I have never intended to use any of the terms on people, and that makes the Urban Dictionary definition to be beside the point (and the puzzle)

Comment: But cow is not the only animal which can be found in the temples. You can also find rats, monkeys and many other animals.

Comment: @manshu But it is still a puzzle, so I fail to see the problem... Cow is just one of the animals normally related to India.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: is it perhaps the celebrated butcher,

> **Kuzma Minin**, from the monument in *Moscow*’s *Red Square*

?

> [image: Minin-Pozharsky monument]

Original partial answer: I presume the capital is

> Moscow

since the Indian `$PLACEOFWORSHIP`-`$ANIMAL` is, of course, a

> mosque-cow.

The shape from the dream is therefore

> square (Mosque-cow’s *red square*).

Comment: Yes! One additional hint is in the title: a "rusty" place to "fly" to.

Comment: You have figured out the highest hand, so if you update the answer saying so, I will give you the bounty:-)

Comment: @Enigma: ok, removed the misleading last sentence of my original answer :-)  Re the “rusty” place to “fly” — what does that point to?  I guessed that was another hint, but couldn’t see any connection from it (at least not more specific than *rusty* = *red*, but you gave us the red directly anyway, so I guess that’s not it).

Comment: Mathias Rust, who flew and landed on the red square during the Cold War

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the final question yet, but:

> It could be related to a casino game, like Black Jack or Poker (*highest hand*).
>  *Red* and *Indian* may refer to native Americans, which are stereotypically known for [running casinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_American_gaming). *Dreaming* may refer to the American dream (getting rich from nowhere with a business, like a casino), or wishing for a particular card.
>  However, the *church-rat* doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: The question is tagged with geography...

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, this must be one of the highest hands in the capital:

> Hanuman statue/temple in New Delhi
>
>  [image: Hanuman statue in New Delhi]

Comment: Wrong capital...

Comment: If you mean American Indian, you should say so (or rather Native American) instead of "red" Indian.

Comment: I don't mean that. Red and Indian is just two separate clues standing next to each other

Comment: Okay, so we're still talking India here? (Sorry if my previous comment sounded snippy)

Comment: I didn't say that, it is still a clue

Answer (score 1):

Clutching at straws:

Hint 3:

> Should be "cow".  A cow is a holy animal in India. Being submissive is "cowed". A male cow is a bull.

Hint 4:

> Is "goat"?

Observation 1:

> Could the answer be:  **Mount Everest**?
>  I can rearrange the letters to form "**Rev. mouse**" which would be a "church-rat"?
>  And Everest is the highest peak...
>  But I can't relate this to any of the hints.

Observation 2 (no idea if it's at all related):

> From the letters of "monastery dog" I can make the following words which are words, or are related to words, in the puzzle and hints:
>  soar (fly), red, God, sermon, rat, dream, star, dome (shapes), most (highest), mastery (upper hand), monastery, dragon, stray, met (visited), mate (friend), go/gone (went), money (capital), mare (female horse), some, goat
>
>  If I could also use J, C and W, then I could make:
>  decagon, jew, enjoy, cow

Comment: Remember that this puzzle is tagged with geography

Comment: I know, I know... but nothing seems to fit...  Okay, I'll update the answer with an idea I had earlier but didn't pursue.

Answer (score 0):

God knows for what reason but this question seems related to the geocaching game. I also find the relevance of the term "Church rat" with this geocaching game. Guess I don't think I'd be able to solve this question but [here](https://www.geocaching.com/track/details.aspx?id=80740)'s my finding.

Hope it helps other explorers. Luck.

Comment: Nope, no geocaching

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer

> Animal Farm ?

Since

> English Church sounds like George (Orwell), and there are horses (Boxer and Clover) and cats and cows and milk

Comment: No. But it is a good idea to play with the words:-)